# Gatsby serve vs Gatsby build and hosting on a web server pros and cons

Tags: gatsby

I have a Gatsby website build, nothing very important, I'm just using it for a Dashboard and being hosted on a Docker linux image. What's the disadvantage if I just run this website using the `gatsby serve` command? vs actually building and hosting on a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the command docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-cli/

In a nutshell, both do exactly what the command name says:

- `build` compiles the app. `serve` serves the already compiled app. Calling `serve` before a `build` will result in an error.